# Python - making list with requirements

Tags: python, list

I have csv file with approx. 220 k of lines. I need to find which lines are closer to points i set up and make a list of next 15 lines. The problem is that i can find closer point, but some of categories (drivers) has only 2 lines close to the point i set up, some of them has 20 lines. I would like to add next 15 lines whether there is 5 or 20 lines close to the points.

The point of this app is to find what time and date drivers are crossing the borders and which way they are going.

```
for record in driver_file_reader:
        
        driver_lat = float(record[3])
        driver_long = float(record[4])
        time = record[6]

        for border in border_list:
            
            border_city = border[0]
            border_country = border[1]
            border_lat = float(border[2])
            border_long = float(border[3])

            distance_from_border = distance(driver_lat, driver_long, border_lat, border_long)

            if distance_from_border <= 1.5:

                if len(lat_list) <= 14 and len(long_list) <= 14:
                    lat_list.append(driver_lat)
                    long_list.append(driver_long)
```

Comment: you can use slicing `list[:15]` to get `15` when you have more than `15`. If you will have less then `15` (ie. `2`) then `list[:15]` gives you `2` - I don't know how you expect to have 15 when you have only 2.

Comment: I have more then 2, but the distance of these 2 is less then 1.5 km. Next of them is more then 1.5 km and they don't show up. I would like to find closest point (which is `if distance_from_border <= 1.5:`) and add to list next 15 items, but problem is that they have more then 1.5 km from point of border.

Comment: maybe create list with all distances (list with items `[distance, lat, long]`), sort this list and then get `[:15]`